# Swig , C++ "include nested too deeply"

Tags: c++, nested, include, swig, include-guards

I am a beginner at c++ and I'm having this problem with nested include files. The code is too big to put here, but this is the part that I'm getting the error:

#### cvblob.h

```c
#ifdef SWIG
%module cvblob
%{
#include "cvblob.h"
%}
#endif

#ifndef CVBLOB_H
#define CVBLOB_H

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#ifndef __CV_BEGIN__
#define __CV_BEGIN__ __BEGIN__
#endif
#ifndef __CV_END__
#define __CV_END__ __END__
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...
```

At **line 4** in the above code (`#iclude "cvblob.h"`), the error happens:

> [package_tracking/cvblob/cvblob.h:26]: (error) #include nested too
>   deeply

The guards are already used, but the error doesn't go away. Sorry that I am not able to put the entire code. If it is not possible to figure it out without the entire code, please answer these questions:

- Should I put the guards (`#ifndef CVBLOB_H`) before the first line?
- Is it necessary to put the guards in all the header files?

Thank you! I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is this code you wrote or is it part of some package?

Comment: I dont remember how to do it correctly for swig, but the `#ifdef` / `#endif`s are not balanced and it looks fishy that you include `cvblob.h` in itself.

Comment: @MaxLanghof it's part of a package. I am just using it.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The code presumably continues after the given snippet (as indicated by the unmatched `extern "C" {`).

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes, it continues. This is the top part of the header file.

Comment: In that case this is some issue related to SWIG integration in OpenCV, which I know absolutely nothing about. The code is not valid C++ (if `SWIG` is defined, which it appears to be) due to the `%` stuff at the top, so I've added the SWIG tag and hope those folks can help you!

Comment: Code with `%module` stuff should only appear in `.i` files and then the SWIG guard does not make sense. Provide a full example, which demonstrates the error